# Is there a 1-1 correspondence between symmetry and group theory?

Tags: mathematical-physics, symmetry, group-theory

The professor in my class of mathematical physics introduces the definition of groups and said that group theory is the mathematics of symmetry.

He gave also some examples of groups such as the set of all real numbers under addition.

My question is what symmetry are we talking about here when we consider the set of all real numbers under addition?

Comment: Indeed  group  theory  is  the  mathematical  language  of  symmetry. Here  is a link of a nice  article  entitled " Symmetry in  Physics : Wigners  legacy " http://www.jptp.uni-bayreuth.de/vorlesungen/symmetry.pdf        It  was  written in 1995 by  Nobel  prize  winner  David  Gross.

Answer (score 6):

1. On one hand, a [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29) $G$ is a purely mathematical concept.
2. On the other hand, given a system $S$ on which a group $G$ [acts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) $G\times S \to S$. The system $S$ then constitutes a (possibly non-linearly realized) *representation* of the group $G$. The system $S$ can in certain cases be *invariant* under the group action, and in such cases we say the system $S$ possesses a $G$-[symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry).
3. In physics, $S$ is typical a set of equations, or an [action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_%28physics%29) (not to be confused with the notion of a [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action)).
4. The Abelian group $G=(\mathbb{R},+)$ that OP mentions is implemented in many physical systems. It could be translation symmetry of a physical system in a given direction, as Maksim Zholudev writes in a comment. But this is just one out of many possibilities, and there is not a 1-1 correspondence between groups and symmetries in a strict mathematical sense.
5. Finally, note that the notion of a group $G$ may be weakened/generalized in several ways, e.g. to a [groupoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid).

Comment: Let me check if I get this right: So a group $G$ is not identified with a symmetry unless the group elements leave some system invariant, right?. Who is OP?. In case when $G$ is the translation symmetry of a physical system in a given direction, what are the representations of the group elements in this case?and what is the quantity that will be invariant under the system translation? (whenever the word symmetry is mentioned, I try to think of a quantity that is left invariant under the effect of the group elements, like equilateral triangle under rotation by $n\times 120$ degrees)

Comment: Well now you have to speak of the difference betweeen actual symmetries, like the symmetry of a circle when the group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ acts by rotations or the dihedral group acting on a regular n-gon (reflections, rotations), with *gauge transformations* which speak about equations and their solutions (prime example being Electrodynamics).  And "OP" means original poster.

Answer (score 2):

There is a one to one correspondence between symmetry and group theory for the simple reason that if A is a symmetry and B is a symmetry, then so is B followed by A.  This implies that symmetries form a group, where the group law is *composition* of maps (a symmetry is a map).

Translation along the real axis is the physical symmetry of time translation.  As pointed out by Wiener, it is an important fact that if we begin an experiment at time $ t =0$ and measured the results at time $t = 4$, the answers will be, physically, the same as if we had started the experiment at time $t=21$ and measured the results at time $t=25$.

This is the reason why Fourier analysis is useful... whenever you have a symmetry group, the representations of that group are useful.  The representations of the translation group are the exponential functions so Fourier analysis, the decomposition of an arbitrary function into combinations of different exponential functions, is useful.